# different configurations files to apache2?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I'm pretty new to this, and reading a lot online, but what configuration is right?

in apache2, some are talking about **httpd.conf**, and have all configuration in one file.

my installation have 2 configuration files for EACH of my virtual sites, one for port 80 and one for 443.

and when I'm reading on apache's website, it looks like that have only one file?

I'm SO confused..

Is there no difference, or is it for different versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache web server uses a single configuration file, however, other files can be included in the config, which makes handling configuration files convenient. For example, in Ubuntu (which, by the way uses `apache2.conf` as the main config file, instead of `httpd.conf`), the contents of each file in `sites-enabled/` and `conf-enabled/` are included, so they effectively become part of the config file.

For this, when the documentation talks about "the" config file, you shouldn't really bother yourself about your config being split into many smaller files, for as long as Apache concerned, they all become one large config in the end.